# Error when install module sale_order_types

Tags: installation, openerp-8

I install this module in v8.0 but error

```
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: sale_order_types.sales_journal"

<p><record id="normal_sale_type" model="sale.order.type">
      <field name="name">Normal Order</field>
      <field name="warehouse_id" ref="stock.warehouse0"/>
      <field name="sequence_id" ref="sale.seq_sale_order"/>
      <field name="journal_id" ref="sales_journal"/>
</record></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sales_journal id is not available in your module. It's available on account module so we need to use that.

Try this,

```
<record id="normal_sale_type" model="sale.order.type">
  <field name="name">Normal Order</field>
  <field name="warehouse_id" ref="stock.warehouse0"/>
  <field name="sequence_id" ref="sale.seq_sale_order"/>
  <field name="journal_id" ref="account.sales_journal"/>
</record>
```

**EDIT :**

`sales_journal` id is related with demo data. So make sure you loaded demo data.

Comment: Hello @Odedra! I've installed that module and the code is like yours (ref="account.sales_journal"), but I'm getting the same error. I've looked for a XML ID "sales_journal" in the module "account", and it's in the file "account/demo/account_minimal.xml", so there's a XML ID "sales_journal" in the module "account". Why am I getting this error then?

Comment: Hello @forvas: make you add `account` module in dependency. At my end, it works fine. If all thing are perfect than check it out weather module is upgrade proper or not. try with generating error something like, thanks

Comment: I've added "account" to the dependencies of the __openerp__.py of sale_order_type. I've also changed the description of the module, to check that the changes were updated before installing it. But still the same error.

Comment: Okay @forvas, got the problem and write it down on answer so may check out that. Thanks

Comment: I've commented the dependency in the __openerp__.py to avoid the error, but I guess what I did is an useless solution, it's working because half module was not installed. How can I check if the demo data was rightly loaded? Looking in the database?

Comment: There are many ways we can check that. For example, check out the list of Customer, from their you may got idea weather demo data is loaded or not. Also you may check out Product list, Account code, type, name or journal and all configuration menu items.. etc..